# Won't print function

Tags: python, printing, try-catch, except

I'm trying to print "print(tuple_list)" but my program keeps going to my except and asking for a new input. Any ideas? thanks

```
def open_file():
    data=open("data_full.txt")
    return data


def process_file(data):
    user_month = input("Enter the number of months (N) which should be \
included in the list of warmest months: ")

    cnt = 0
    tuple_list = []
    header = data.readline()
    header = header.strip().split()
    #print(header)
    while True:    
        try:
            for line in data:
                cnt+= 1
                field = line.strip().split()
                line_list = [int(n) for n in field]
                #print(line_list)

                year = line_list[0]

                for i in range(1,13):
                    tuple_list.append(year,header[i],line_list[i])

                    print(tuple_list)      
            break

        except: 
            print("***Unusual circumstance. Try Again***")
            user_month = input("Enter the number of months (N) which should \
be included in the list of warmest months: ")

def main():
    while True:
        try:
            f=open_file()
            break
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("Invalid file name. Try Again.")
    process_file(f)
    f.close()
main()
```

Comment: What Exception are you getting?  import traceback, then within the except block print out a stack trace.  It will tell you which line is failing.  In order to prevent this question from being deleted for not being complete, you better add an exception stack trace with relevant error message quick.

Comment: Why do you even *have* that try-except? It's not doing anything useful. You're not even using `user_month`, so getting a new `user_month` won't fix any errors.

Comment: Generally speaking, bare `except` statements are problematic for exactly this reason.  The only thing you know is that _something_ went wrong -- It could be a programming error, input error or something else -- and you have no way of knowing.  You should almost always _only_ catch exceptions that you expect to happen and nothing more.

Comment: Change the bare `except:` to `except Exception as exc:`, then in the following print use something like `print("***Unusual circumstance:", exc, "\nTry again***")` to see what's causing the problem.

Comment: The best way to find out why an `except` block is being entered is to take your code out of the `try..except` structure. Then you'll see the traceback.

Comment: After you are done getting a stack trace and including it in your question, then it is customary for you to trim down the irrelevancies of your code, and ask a SPECIFIC question, not just copypasta your entire code with the request for help.  As it stands, this question is not a welcome artifact on stackoverflow until you remedy both of these serious issues.  Give us the stack trace, AND reduce the program to 5 lines that we can easily reproduce.  Had you done this, you'll find your question is most likely already answered 10 times already on stackoverflow.